# My aunt is paying for my trip to the US. How can I demonstrate that when applying for a B1/B2 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, proof-of-funds

I'm studying Master in Korean, I will graduate in March 2016. My aunt invited me and also guarantee any costs during the travel time. I just have transcript, family ties documents. So what is the necessary to prove that I will not go to US for living?

Comment: Are you planning to travel before or after you finish your studies?  I suppose it is to be after.  It seems it may be difficult for you.  Are you planning to seek a job or continued study before your trip?

Comment: Tell customs the truth.

Comment: Be ready with your answers at the visa interview. That is when they decide in a moment whether you will receive a visa or not.

Comment: @phoog  I will go to US for vacation after I finished my study. I have planning to seek a job in my country. Could you suggest for me what is the best reason for my case?

Comment: @StephanBijzitter They will accept if I tell them the truth? Could you give me some comments?

Comment: Well, that's still a bit of a guess. But if you do not (fully) tell the truth, people will think you're keeping secrets. Customs don't like secrets. Answer their questions in short, but clear manner. Telling too much detail is never good: if they want more detail, they'll ask for it. If they ask "Why are you here?" you can simply reply "I am going to visit my aunt, she lives here!".

Comment: Just be honest with the customs officer. 95% of the time, they will just ask you the reason for your visit to the US. If you are a student in Korea, tell that you will be returning to Korea for studies. That shows proof that you will return home.

Comment: What's your citizenship?

Comment: IMO it looks like it might be difficult for you to get a visa from the USA, since you have no ties to your country (Lump Sum of Cash in the bank, real estate, business, a job etc.). If you can prove them that you will definitely returning to you country(?), then you will have chances. From my perspective, it looks like you are going to your aunt right after graduation for a bit of job search. Just my two cents.

Comment: Did you travel to the US eventually?

Comment: Hi everyone, I got the US visa for 1 year. everything was work well. Just demonstrate all things by honestly answer. And show the officer clear reasons you want to travel in the US as well as some documentary about some constrain in your country.

Answer (score 1):

Show your school transcript, and maybe print out potential job postings that you're considering. Also show them that you speak Korean and you have decent chances to get a job in Korea (since you're applying for a visa, I'm assuming that you're not Korean, cause you'd be eligible for VWP. I'm also assuming that you live in Korea).

Just be honest. The main thing is that you need to show them that you're not going to stay in US *illegally*. Living South Korea is quite an advantage, since it's also a developed country (i.e. why would you stay illegally in US when you can stay legally in Korea), so I wouldn't worry much. I remember my interview in an embassy in Frankfurt when I had Azerbaijani passport was shorter than interviews of Germans. I had a German permanent residence back then, so it showed that I don't break immigration laws.